# How to append data after the last row in google spreadsheet using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

Currently, I am able to import data from another spreadsheet into the first row of the new spreadsheet. But I was looking for ways to **append the data after the last row** in Google Spreadsheet using the Google App Script.

```
function importData() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19VSMmYDmLI4z4cIXjPmufn9d7Q-sL-xqzCCUVV4y7VU').
    getSheetByName('data').getRange('A:D').getValues();

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet3').
    getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For single row:**
[appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

**For multiple rows:** [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

```js
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```